# Rails 'required: true' does not work fully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple_form with a grouped collection select and two input fields. I have a required: true on both fields, but it still allows empty input through. The little 'required' asterisk appears next to the field name, but that's it. Is there any way I can prevent empty input from going through the form?

new.rb

```
<h1>New Article</h1>

<%= render 'form', article: @article %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path(category_id: params[:category_id]) %>
```

_form.rb

```
<%= simple_form_for(article, html: {class: 'form-vertical'}) do |f| %>
  <% if article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h4><%= pluralize(article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h4>

      <ul>
      <% article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">

  <%# field being selected, parent collection, subcollection, displayed, key, value %>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :subcategory_id, Category.all,:subcategories,:name, :id,:name, {required: true} %>
    <%= f.input :title, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :content, input_html: { rows: 20 }, required: true%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    if params[:category_id].blank? && params[:subcategory_id].blank?
      @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:subcategory_id].blank?
      @articles = Article.where(category_id: params[:category_id])
    else
      @articles = Article.where(subcategory_id: params[:subcategory_id]).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @parameters = article_params
    @parameters[:category_id] = Subcategory.find(@parameters[:subcategory_id]).category_id
    @article = Article.new(@parameters)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title,:content,:subcategory_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: just add `validates_presence_of :something` to your `Article` model (title, content, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use validations, that logic is done inside the model.
Make sure you read and undertand the [ActiveRecord Validations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) because it will save you a lot of time.
Example taken from the guide:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end



Person.create(name: "John Doe").valid? # => true
Person.create(name: nil).valid? # => false
```

Basically when the object is saved, it runs the validations and if it's not valid it will fill the errors variable with the messages.

Comment: Right, that's what I didn't do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per simple documentation of rails. Your model should look like this(suppose i wanted to validate presence of first_name last_name and compnay_name):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  validates :company_name, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
end
```

Now after this you are ready to go, presence: true will validate data before saving it to the database. A good practice is to add a validation to the front end too. which is add require: true to your form_for helper.

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, required: true ,autocomplete: "email", class: "border p-3 w-100 my-2" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple form documentation states...

> By default all inputs are required. When the form object has presence
>   validations attached to its fields, Simple Form tells required and
>   optional fields apart. For performance reasons, this detection is
>   skipped on validations that make use of conditional options, such as
>   :if and :unless.

Which means that all you need to do is add into your model/article.rb file

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
```